# Jenkins/Docker: How to force pull base image before build

Tags: docker, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

Docker allows passing the `--pull` flag to `docker build`, e.g. `docker build --pull -t myimage .`. How can I enforce pulling the base image with a pipeline script in my `Jenkinsfile`? This way I want to ensure that the build always uses the latest container image despite of the version available locally.

```
node('docker') {
    def app

    stage('Checkout') {
        checkout scm
    }

    stage('Build image') {
        docker.withRegistry('https://myregistry.company.com', 'dcr-jenkins') {
            app = docker.build "myimage"
        }
    }

    stage('Publish image') {
        docker.withRegistry('https://myregistry.company.com', 'dcr-jenkins') {
            app.push("latest")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-55821

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[additionalBuildArgs](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-42693) does the job.

Example:

```
pipeline {
    agent {
        label "docker"
    }

    stages {
        […]

        stage('Build image') {
            agent {
                dockerfile {
                    reuseNode true
                    registryUrl "https://registry.comapny.com"
                    registryCredentialsId "dcr-jenkins"
                    additionalBuildArgs "--pull --build-arg APP_VERSION=${params.APP_VERSION}"
                    dir "installation/app"
                }
            }

            steps {
                script {
                    docker {
                        app = docker.build "company/app"
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        […]
    }

}
```

Answer (score 11):

The most straight-forward answer is to use the second argument to `docker.build`

```
stage('Build image') {
    docker.withRegistry('https://myregistry.company.com', 'dcr-jenkins') {
        app = docker.build("myimage", "--pull .")
    }
}
```

If you don't supply it then it just defaults to `.`, so if you pass in anything you must also include the context yourself.

You can find this in the "Pipeline Syntax - Global Variable Reference".  Just add `/pipeline-syntax/globals` to the end of any Jenkins URL (i.e. http://localhost:8080/job/myjob/pipeline-syntax/globals)

Answer (score 0):

`docker rmi <image>` at the beginning of your script, before `docker build --pull`. The image will not exist locally when `docker build --pull` executes, so it will be downloaded fresh each time.